# User shown three times as a recent badge recipient?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

[Thepaulpage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161710/thepaulpage) is shown twice on the Yearling badge page.

[image: screen shot of: Thepaulpage is shown twice]

I was curious, and it turns out, that user is “3 years, 8 months” old. So intuitively, it doesn’t even make sense for this person to be listed here, but I suppose you could be idle for a while and then have a year of activity? (No idea, pure conjecture.)

Comment: Or perhaps an account merge?

Comment: It's actually there 3 times

Comment: @animuson Curious why you removed “and perhaps shouldn’t, at all?” from the title. It was intended to signal an additional (dimension of the) bug.

Comment: Titles should be short and concise. There is no way those words can fit in a _perfect_ title, they were unimportant thoughts that should be sneakily and silently stated inside the body of the question.

Comment: animuson is correct that this is a result of a merge.

Comment: “By design.” Amazing. This could only make sense to a programmer. Granted, we all are, but this software is supposed to power a whole network.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like his account got merged into another that didn't have the badges yet, [so all of his badges were re-awarded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161710/thepaulpage?tab=activity).

Comment: Got it. So, am I supposed to accept an answer if this is a bug? Should I wait until someone says it’s added to a tracker or something?

Comment: It's not a bug. This is normal behavior for account merges, and probably happens more often than you notice.

Comment: How is this not a bug? The page should not show the same user three times, because that is not useful to people viewing the page.

Comment: Depends on your definition of usefulness. For me, that page is completely useless. I couldn't care less who the badge has been awarded to recently. But for *any* badge out there that can be awarded multiple times, you get listed in the recently awarded page *every* time you earn that badge. If you get 50 Nice Answer badges in a row and no one else gets one during that time, you'll be listed as the last 50 people who got the badge.

Comment: “For me, that page is completely useless.” Fair enough. But seeing a reward that can only happen once a year being given to the same person twice in a row can be confusing. I mean, it was clearly confusing enough that I filed a bug report, right?

Comment: *shrugs* What would you have them do? Calculate when the badge should have been awarded originally and manually modify the date? Seems like a lot of effort for an edge case scenario.

Comment: The bug would seem to lie with the merge algorithm. Depending on implementation, it may want to backdate badges or exclude them from being inserted into the recent badges list.